# Installing Anaconda on Ubuntu, getting BrokenProcessPool error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda

I am installing anaconda on my Linux machine. I followed the instructions here. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/ 
However, after selecting the location for the installation, I get an error

```
PREFIX=/home/iris/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                    
  File "entry_point.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[9196] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more appropriate for [Anaconda Issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: look at my answer, perhaps a "not enough RAM" memory issue

Comment: My issue was that I was out of space

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error by not having enough memory (RAM) at disposal for the installation to complete for the Anaconda Power9 installer; in detail I executed the installation on a remote node (srun -i, with slurm scheduler, I have a multi-arch cluster) and it failed lot of times, the problem has been solved by raisin' the RAM memory for the task to 5GB, --mem=5G solved the issue.